# UIVideoEditorController lost video resolution

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avfoundation, uivideoeditorcontroller

I am trying to use UIVideoEditorController to edit my video, but it seems to lose my video resolution. My original video was `720 x 1280`, but after using the `UIVideoEditorController`, the quality becomes `360 x 640`.

I tried to set the `videoQuality` to be `UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh` or even `UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeIFrame1280x720`, but that doesn't help.

I am working on the iPad and here are my code:

```
self.editorController = [[[UIVideoEditorController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.editorController.videoPath = self.tempVideoPath;
self.editorController.delegate = self;
self.editorController.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;

CKLog(@"%d", self.editorController.videoQuality);

self.popOverController = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.editorController] autorelease];
self.popOverController.delegate = self;
self.popOverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(700, 700);
[self.popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) inView:self.videoView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem right now.

Comment: I'm still having this problem - it seems to occur because I'm using AVFoundation frameworks to record, and then using UIVIdeoEditorController to edit - but it's like it's missing some sort of metadata that UIVideoEditorController needs

Comment: Hello Guys any solution this problem? I am using same as @Louis

Comment: I'm experience the issue in iOS 8.2 and iOS 8.3, code written in Swift.

Answer (score -2):

According to the UIVideoEditorController documentation:

> A UIVideoEditorController object, or video editor, manages the
>   system-supplied user interface for trimming video frames from the
>   start and end of a previously recorded movie **as well as reencoding to
>   lower quality**...

The UIVideoEditorController class has a property called `videoQuality`. It allows us to choose the video quality when saving the trimmed video. (The default value is `UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeLow`)

`UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh` uses the highest-quality video recording supported for the active camera on the device. It looks much better, but still seems to lose a little of the original resolution.